# Installation openjms on linux

Tags: java, linux, jms

I would like to install openJMS on my linux machine
http://openjms.sourceforge.net/
I have downloaded the file then extract it. 
But I am blocked at this point.

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help http://openjms.sourceforge.net/adminguide/install.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard for us to help you with the short explanation you have given. What exactly did you try (can you write it as a step-by-step)? Be specific: what did you type? where did you save the file? Also: what exact error did you see? what were you expecting instead? the more you give us, the easier it will be for us to help you, otherwise we're just guessing...

Comment: klog> http://openjms.sourceforge.net/adminguide/install.html helped but I still block in the point where I have I can't run the open JMS.
Taryn East > I don't know how to properly install the file openjms-0.7.7-beta-1.tar.gz describe in this link openjms.sourceforge.net/adminguide/install.html

Comment: I have extract the file in the folder desktop. /home/theo/desktop
I don't have extraction error. I just don't know when the file is extract what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have JAVA_HOME setup for your distro. Google it.

Then after extracting, you will see a bin folder, from there, you can start using file in the extracted directory "bin/startup.sh" to start openjsm. You don't need installation as such. Only extraction. There will be other various scripts in bin directory of extracted file like openjms.sh, shutdown.sh etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I got it